# How to use slice and select the middle characters for 3 different scenarios

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with the column Date contains from unwanted characters , I need to have only Y,M,D .

Scenario 1: 
His_205_26Oct2017

Scenario 2 : 
His_40_26Oct2017

Scenario 3 : 
His_3_26Oct2017

```
  ScenarioDate
    His_205_26Oct2017
    His_359_24Mar2017
    His_380_23Feb2017
    His_392_07Feb2017
    His_40_14Jun2018
    His_2_12Jul2018
```

I tried using below code

```
df2['ScenarioDate'].map(lambda x: str(x)[7:])
```

But I got different output for

Scenario 1: 
_26Oct2017

Scenario 2 : 
26Oct2017

Scenario 3 : 
Oct2017

I need to have output as "26Oct2017" for all 3 scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with pattern for match value after `_` with 2 integers, 3 characters and then 4 integers:

```
df['date'] = df['ScenarioDate'].str.extract('_(\d{2}[a-zA-Z]{3}\d{4})')
print (df)
            ScenarioDate       date
0      His_205_26Oct2017  26Oct2017
1      His_359_24Mar2017  24Mar2017
2      His_380_23Feb2017  23Feb2017
3      His_392_07Feb2017  07Feb2017
4       His_40_14Jun2018  14Jun2018
5        His_2_12Jul2018  12Jul2018
6   His_205_26Oct2017_AD  26Oct2017
7  His_205_26Oct2017_ABC  26Oct2017
```

Comment: Thank you jezrael, I have one more scenario
{ His_205_26Oct2017_AD
 His_205_26Oct2017_ABC
 His_205_26Oct2017_M}
how to gohead in this scenario

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd

df['new date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ScenarioDate'].split('_')[-1])
```